# Bypass OpenVPN on Linux Router for a specific IP on LAN

Tags: openvpn, router

I use an Archlinux as a router on a computer on my network to encrypt all the Internet traffic through VPN. But I need to bypass Openvpn for one device on LAN. Its IP address is always 192.168.0.111.

I Have 3 main interface:

```
enp4s0 which is my WAN
enp1s0f0 which is my LAN
tun0 which is Openvpn Interface
```

My Iptables' rules are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# enp1s0f0 is LAN (Distribute Internet Across Local Area Network or Devices on LAN)
# enp4s0 is WAN (Provide internet)
# tun0 is Openvpn Interface

EXT1="tun0"
EXT2="enp4s0"
INT="enp1s0f0"

iptables -t nat -F
iptables -F

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT


iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXT1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXT2 -j MASQUERADE


iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXT2 -o $INT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INT -o $EXT2 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXT1 -o $INT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INT -o $EXT1 -j ACCEPT
```

Everything will go through vpn unless I specify an address (destination address) in ovpn config, so it bypasses openvpn for that specific site or domain. But in addition to that I want one of my LAN device (192.168.0.111) to bypass all traffic and go through my WAN directly.

When I specify it on ovpn config that device loses/drops all connection and has no send and receive at all. When I use ip route the same thing happens. I know it is my lack of knowledge.

I try to do it with openvpn config to no avail.

I research a lot, but the information was too complex for me.

ip route or iptables may have a simple way to do it for me. Can anyone explain to me how? Simple enough so I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to find a way.

First I define a rule name eman to rt_tables (eman is an arbitrary name):

```
echo 200 eman>> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Then I add the IP address of my machine to the newly created table (Note that this IP belongs to the machine which I want to bypass OpenVPN and connect directly to my main gateway):

```
ip rule add from 192.168.0.111 table eman
```

Then route that table (eman) through my main (WAN) interface (enp4s0) via its gateway which is 192.168.100.1

```
ip route add default via 192.168.100.1 dev enp4s0 table eman
```

Then flush the cache:

```
ip route flush cache
```

If there is another device (for example 192.168.0.113) I can easily add that to the table:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.0.113 table eman
```